# Algorithm for degrading data

Tags: algorithm

I have a database with some data types like A, B, C...

What I'm looking for is an algorithm to tell, at some point *t*, how well known the data type is.

For example, if the database is like:

```
Type | t |
-----+---+
  A  | 0 
  B  | 1
  A  | 2
  A  | 3
  C  | 4
...  | ...
Let's say that B doesn't appear anymore and A appears a lot.
```

The algorithm for *t = 100* would return a very small value for B, because B only happened in *t = 1*, but a large value for A since A happened a lot. But if after *t = 100* B appeared a lot, then in *t = 150* the algorithm would return a large value for B. In the same sense, if after *t = 100* A never appears the algorithm would return a smaller value for A, but not that small since it appeared a lot before *t = 100*.

I believe I'm looking for some kind of degrading algorithm or something like that. If anyone have any ideas for what kind of algorithm I should look for I would be really happy!

Sorry if what I want is not very clear, I can try to explain better later.

Thank You!

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Something like an exponential moving average, the time series being binary (Type is A / is not A)? Or for that matter any moving average?

Comment: @Nabla, I believe there is not enough information given, to decide on type of autoregression.

Comment: @divanov Yes, that's why I wrote it as a comment and question. I expected the questioner to answer with more details / requirements.

Comment: @Nabla, thank you for your response! I don't know how these techniques work, but I will definitely take a look on them. So, I don't know what type of autoregression I should use. But the thing is that I'm looking for an algorithm that takes account the frequency and duration of each occurrence of the types (actually I'm dealing with human activity) in the database to give the final value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some sort of "recently much used" metric, you could use an exponential average for each. I.e., start `a(0) = b(0) = c(0) = d(0) = 0`, and then each time you see an `A` do:

```
a(t) = p * 1 + (1 - p) * a(t - 1)
b(t) =         (1 - p) * b(t - 1)
c(t) =         (1 - p) * c(t - 1)
d(t) =         (1 - p) * d(t - 1)
```

and similarly for the others. Here `0 <= p <= 1`. A high `p` values recent appearances more, a low one favors history.

I'm sure you can cook up something along those lines that is suited for your use.